# k disjoint triangles with graph splitting to two distinct groups

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, randomized-algorithms, colorings, parameterized-complexity

Please note that this question is different than [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121199/color-coding-to-get-an-fpt-algoirthm-for-k-disjoint-triangles).

The $k$-disjoint triangles problem is as follows:

> Input: A graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k\in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Output: Are there $k$ vertex-disjoint triangles in $G$?

An FPT algorithm is presented [here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/seminaires/AGAPE/lecture_notes/Agape%2009%20-%20Daniel%20Marx%20-%20FPT%20algorithmic%20techniques%20-%20Printable.pdf) (starting from slide 60). The algorithm uses color-coding and relies on dynamic programming to determine if a solution is highlighted (each vertex in the solution group is colored with a distinct color). The running time of the algorithm is $O^{*}((2e)^{3k})$.

Now, Let's assume that we get a group $X \subseteq V$ of vertices, and the problem changes: Are there $k$ vertex-disjoint triangles in $G$ where one vertex is from $X$ and the other two are from $V \setminus X$?

I need to find an algorithm whose running time is $O^{*}((2e)^{2k})$. I tried coloring all vertices from $X$ in a single color, but I couldn't find a way to avoid the duplicate choices of vertices from $X$. I also try to color each vertex from $X$ in a distinct color that is different from the colors of $V\setminus X$ but the running time is higher.

Can you propose a coloring method that will highlight a possible solution within the required complexity? Should I try something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color the vertices in $V \setminus X$ with $2k$ colors at random. With probability $e^{-2k}$, the $V \setminus X$ vertices of your $k$ disjoint triangles will be highlighted.

Suppose without loss of generality that $X = [m]$.
Using dynamic programming, determine for each subset $S \subseteq [2k]$ and $i \in [m]$ whether there exist $|S|/2$ disjoint triangles using the colors in $S$ and vertices $1,\ldots,i$ of $X$. This takes time $O^*(2^{2k})$.